# CakePHP 3 - Same layout for actions with the same name

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need all actions Add() have the same layout.
There is a way to have that without editing every single action Add() in every single controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `beforeFilter()` callback in your app controller, check the action name, and set the layout accordingly.

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    if($this->request->param('action') === 'add') {
        $this->layout = 'some_layout';
    }
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > The App Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Request Life-cycle Callbacks](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Request Parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-parameters)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Layouts](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#layouts)**